# Spacewalk install via proxy

Tags: proxy, spacewalk

I'm building a spacewalk system that only has access to the internet via a proxy. I can yum update via the proxy without problem. However, When I perform step 2.

> Blockquote
>   yum install -y spacewalk-repo --tmprepo=https://copr-be.cloud.fedoraproject.org/results/%40spacewalkproject/spacewalk-2.9/epel-7-x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml --nogpg

Failure. I have proof in my logs that the plugin is ignoring proxy settings. Including env variables like https_proxy. Since I can't get the system to use a proxy and I can't ignore the proxy. Any ideas on how I can sidestep this?

Answer (score 0):

If the tmprepo is indeed ignoring the proxy settings, you could download the repo file with wget first, and point --tmprepo to the local file :

```
wget https://copr-be.cloud.fedoraproject.org/results/%40spacewalkproject/spacewalk-2.9/epel-7-x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml
yum install -y spacewalk-repo --tmprepo=./repomd.xml --nogpg
```

The plugin should be able to handle a local file : https://jsmith.fedorapeople.org/drafts/SMG/html/Software_Management_Guide/ch06s21.html

Answer (score 0):

@Ben-Banso Thanks for the help. I did actually get around this on my own. I installed the GUI on the system with "yum groupinstall 'Server with GUI'" and then set a system wide proxy setting via the Gnome panel network tool (Sorry I don't know the official name). Once the proxy was set this way i was able to run the command that was previously failing.